# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in django alongside server also disconnected

Tags: django, python-3.x, matplotlib, mpld3

i'm trying to plot line chart using Matplotlib and mpld3 with Django . its working properly but if i hit refresh button in browser to reload the page suddenly server getting stopped with error message 
`[Segmentation fault (core dumped)]`

bellow i mentioned my code . thanks in advance !!

### in views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt , mpld3

def index(request):
   fig = plt.figure()
   plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],'r--')
   g = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
   return render(request,'index.html',{'a' : g})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fix simply add the below mentioned line along with your import statement.

`import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('Agg')`

matplotlib.use('Agg') should be next to import matplotlib
Hope this will help you..

Comment: it's helps me a lot . you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem between Django runserver and matplotlib with Django 2.0 and python 3.X.
Waiting for a patch for this problem, meanwhile, I solved it using gunicorn with nginx as frontend instead of the Django embedded server.